# how to sys.exit this python application on any exception thrown

Tags: python-3.x, ethereum

I would like to learn how to exit my python application if any exception occurs. the project below generates a random private key, converts to ethereum wallet address, checks the balance of the wallet and then writes values to mysql. the application works flawlessly, except from time to time i run into issues. For example, loss of network or api rate limit reached etc. i will list the exceptions i see below and label as exception 1:, 2: etc. I've experimented with different variations of try except finally, but to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

My python app.

```
import os
from ethereum import utils
import time
import urllib.request
import json
import secrets
import mysql.connector

# Initialize main variables 
addressCount = 20 # Address number by request
allAddress = []
allHexNumber = {}
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="user",
  passwd="pwd",
  database="ethereum"
)

for i in range(addressCount):
    # Generate random eth address
    hex_number = secrets.token_hex(32)
    rawAddress = utils.privtoaddr(hex_number)
    accAddress = utils.checksum_encode(rawAddress)

    # Add address to list with its hex number
    allAddress.append(accAddress)
    allHexNumber[accAddress] = hex_number

# Join all the addresses by a ","
allAddressStr = ",".join(allAddress)

# Make the request
url = "https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balancemulti&address=" + allAddressStr + "&tag=latest&apikey=PutYourApiHere"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())

# Get and display the result for each balance with its hex number
allResults = data['result']

for result in allResults:
    address = result['account']
    hex_number = allHexNumber[address]
    balance = result['balance'] 
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()   
    sql = "INSERT INTO ether2 (privkey, privadd, balance) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    val = (hex_number, address, balance)
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)
    mydb.commit()
```

## Exception 1:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1326, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1240, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1286, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1235, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1006, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 946, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1409, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "intesting.py", line 36, in <module>
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 542, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1369, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1329, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer>
```

## Exception 2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1326, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1240, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1286, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1235, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1006, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 946, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1402, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 917, in connect
    self.sock = self._create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 787, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "intesting.py", line 36, in <module>
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 542, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1369, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1329, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `try` `except` pair to catch the exception

```
try:
    ...
    ...
except :
    print("Failed")
    exit(0)
```

And if you want something to run always after the code executes, regardless error occurs or not, use :

```
try:
    ...
    ...
except :
    print("Failed")
    exit(0)
finally:
    print("This runs always")
```

In the case of your code,

```
try :
    url = "https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&
    action=balancemulti&address=" + allAddressStr + "&tag=latest&
    apikey=ValidAPI"
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data = json.loads(response.read())
except:
    print("Error")
```

Comment: I included my try except finally attempt, its not working for any of the exceptions thrown. do i have it positioned incorrectly?

Comment: You might have, I don't see the try - except in your code. Can you edit your code?

Comment: Place the try - except in the for loop

Comment: makes total sense. i can have this try except statement at multiple points in the script. For example, connecting to the db, making an url call, writing to the db. Thank you, i dont know why i was looking at it as a catch all..